# Android studio format code won't auto break line

Tags: android, android-studio

```
tempCanvas.drawArc(cx - mInnerCircleRadius, cy + mInnerCircleRadius,cy + mInnerCircleRadius,cy + mInnerCircleRadius);
```

For example, the above code is too long, so I want to break the line at every `,`. Eclipse will do it but Android Studio won't break the line when I hit `format code`. Is there any method to do it?

Answer (score 91):

In Android Studio (and probably any other IDE) you don't break (wrap) lines by `,` or any other character, you define a maximum line width and set the formatter to ensure the maximum line width is not exceeded.

You do that on `File -> Settings` on Windows, or in `Preferences` on Mac OS.

To do this in Android Studio go to

```
File > Settings > Editor > Code Style
```

and set `Right margin (columns)` to `120` (or the line width you want)

Now go to

```
File > Settings > Editor > Code Style > Java > Wrapping and Braces (tab)
```

and `check` the checkbox `Ensure right margin in not exceeded`

Apply the changes and press OK

Now in the editor, to format your code to that line width, press:

```
Code > Reformat Code...
```

Done

In Mac OS instead of `File > Settings` go to `Preferences`, follow the same steps.

Comment: Circa 2017, I can no longer find the "Preferences" menu. However, doing the second part (File -> Settings, etc.) is sufficient.

Comment: February 2018. "Ensure right margin in not exceeded" doesn't exist.

Comment: Just downloaded Android Studio 3.0, the lastest version, and `Ensure right margin in not exceeded` does exist in `Wrapping and Braces` tab. Have in mind that in Windows you find it in `File > Settings`, in Mac OS in `Preferences`.

Answer (score 12):

```
Configure > Settings > Editor > 'Use soft wraps in editor'
```

Or right click on the divider where you can choose to show line numbers, and click 'Use soft wraps'

This won't break your code at your commas, but it will wrap your code so it's not too long to read.

Answer (score 12):

On the latest Android Studio:

1. Goto `File > Settings > Editor > Code style > Java > Wrapping and Braces`
2. Change `do not wrap` to `wrap if long` for all the items
3. Now Select the portion of the text you want to format and press `ctrl + Alt + L`

[image]

Answer (score 4):

```
File> Settings > Editor > Code Style > Kotlin > 'Set from...' - 'Predefined Style' - 'Kotlin style guide'
```

when you want to use predefined code style for Kotlin in Android Studio/Idea (general rules from [Coding Conventions](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/coding-conventions.html))

Answer (score 2):

File -> Settings > Editor > Code Style.

Then select Wrap on typing **CHECKBOX**.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't wanna wrap a line:

`File` -> `Settings` -> `Editor` -> `Soft Wraps` -> **Uncheck** `Use soft wraps in editor`

Answer (score 0):

As a reminder to others visiting this question, you can also manually add line breaks by hitting <kbd>enter</kbd> after the commas or other appropriate places in the code. Android Studio will automatically indent it. This makes long lines more readable.

```
tempCanvas.drawArc(
        cx - mInnerCircleRadius, // You can also add comments 
        cy + mInnerCircleRadius, // to different parts of a line
        cy + mInnerCircleRadius, // this way.
        cy + mInnerCircleRadius);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can make it automatically for all files by

`Editor` -> `General` -> `Soft-Wraps`, check the `Soft-wrap files` and input needed filetype (for example *.java) in input field, now any new and even opened files will autowrap long strings. No any additional actions needed.